# Reflection: Get all subproperties

Tags: c#, reflection, propertyinfo

I have a List that contains objects and each of these objects contains a lot of properties of several types, and each of these properties contains subproperties aswell.

I need to get all the properties via Reflection and store them in one PropertyInfo[] ...

Is this even possible with reflection? I really need to do it via reflection...

Comment: P.S. : I do not know how many subproperties the object contains during coding, ist allways different

Comment: please read the article [ask] ... what have you tried? (short but complete example) example datastructure and expected result help a ton too

Comment: And what about cycles? It's pretty easy to get into an infinite loop over the properties. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as "sub properties" - properties are of a certain type, can have values of a certain type (ie. a subclass of the property type), and that type can have properties of its own.

You can use recursion for this:

```
List<PropertyInfo> properties = new List<PropertyInfo>();
foreach (object obj in myList)
{
    properties.AddRange(GetDeepProperties(obj, ...));
}

PropertyInfo[] array = properties.ToArray();
```

...

```
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetDeepProperties(object obj, BindingFlags flags)
{
    // Get properties of the current object
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in obj.GetType().GetProperties(flags))
    {
        yield return property;

        object propertyValue = property.GetValue(obj, null);
        if (propertyValue == null)
        {
            // Property is null, but can still get properties of the PropertyType
            foreach (PropertyInfo subProperty in property.PropertyType.GetProperties(flags))
            {
                yield return subProperty;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Get properties of the value assiged to the property
            foreach (PropertyInfo subProperty = GetDeepProperties(propertyValue))
            {
                yield return subProperty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is just an example:

- I have not tried or even compiled it
- you'll get a `StackOverflowException` if somewhere in this "property tree" objects are pointing to eachother
- it misses null checks and exception handling (property getters can throw exceptions)
- it ignores the existence of indexed properties

I don't know what you want to do with this array - the reference to the object from which each `PropertyInfo` was created is lost, so you can't get or set their values anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] result = GetAllPropertyInfos(typeof(Example)).ToArray(); ;

        foreach (string property in result.Select(p => string.Format("{0} : {1}",p.Name,p.PropertyType.Name)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(property);
        }

    }

    static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetAllPropertyInfos(Type type)
    {
        List<PropertyInfo> result = new List<PropertyInfo>();
        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in type.GetProperties())
        {
            result.Add(propertyInfo);
            result.AddRange(GetAllPropertyInfos(propertyInfo.PropertyType));
        }
        return result;
    }
}

class Example
{
    public AnotherExample AProperty { get; set; }
    public int AnotherProperty { get; set; }
}

class AnotherExample
{
    public int YetAnotherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
AProperty : AnotherExample
YetAnotherProperty : Int32
AnotherProperty : Int32
```